# How to send full HTML (loaded after JS) via API on browser action click - Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

For the past 2 days I'm trying to get HTML that is seen on a webpage to be sent via Chrome extension to a specific API endpoint (With URL).

The main problem is that not all HTML content that is seen on a webpage at a moment when Browser action is clicked is sent. For example if website is made in a way that injects HTML at a later time, say when a user clicks "Show more horses" after 1 min after reading through the page - these newly added horses will not be sent.

If user would have to click another button after Browser Action I would be fine with it. The main problem I believe I have is that I am grabbing the HTML right after the content is loaded. I've been trying to change this but with no luck.
After looking at various StackOverflow posts and Chrome Ext. docs I've got the following code that successfully sends the URL and HTML - but not all HTML if it has been added say after 1 min:

manifest.json

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Horses extension",
  "version": "0.3",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_title": "Horses extension",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

background.js

```js
// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender) {
  // First, validate the message's structure
  if ((msg.from === 'content') && (msg.subject === 'showPageAction')) {
    // Enable the page-action for the requesting tab
    chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
  }
});
```

Content.js

```js
// Inform the background page that
// this tab should have a page-action
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  from:    'content',
  subject: 'showPageAction'
});

// Listen for messages from the popup
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, response) {
  // First, validate the message's structure
  if ((msg.from === 'popup') && (msg.subject === 'horsesInformation')) {
    var a=[]
    a.push(msg.url)
    a.push(document.all[0].outerHTML)
    response(a)
  }
});
```

popup.js

```js
window.addEventListener ("load", sendJobOpeningInfo, false);

function sendHorsesInformation(url_and_html) {

  var jsInitChecktimer = setInterval (checkForJS_Finish, 5000);
  
  function checkForJS_Finish (){
    clearInterval (jsInitChecktimer);
    
//GOAL: Post HTML and Domain to API
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://lvh.me:3000/api_url_xyz
      type: "POST",
      data: {url: url_and_html[0], html_source: url_and_html[1]},
      success: function (data) {
        var horsesTitle = document.getElementById('horses-title')
        horsesTitle.append("Success!!")
      }
    });
  }
}

// ...query for the active tab...
chrome.tabs.query({
  active: true,
  currentWindow: true
}, function (tabs) {
  // ...and send a request for the Domain info...
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
      tabs[0].id,
      {from: 'popup', subject: 'horsesInformation', url: tabs[0].url},
      // ...also specifying a callback to be
      //called from the receiving end (content script)
      sendHorsesInformation);
});
```

popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3 id="horses-title"></h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

What would I have to change that all content that is seen on a webpage (even after JS injection) is sent to my API endpoint? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is a "given time"? What is the purpose of your extension (it seems meaningless)? There no automatic reliable method anyway, but you can delay for 20 seconds instead of 5. Oh, and of course use `load` event of `window` in the content script to send the message.

Comment: Hey, yes I changed what we're searching for to exclude long variable names etc. We are for example trying to extract job opening from a site such as https://www.salliemae.com/about/careers/. After you click "Search" for job openings all are shown. Then I imagined I would click chrome extension and I would pass all html content that is seen - all job openings to an API endpoint. I have added the load event of window in the context of content.js but it seems it's getting ignored. How should I do that? Have pasted the way I tried it below in my next comment ...

Comment: Have tried like this but it's not working :/ 
` window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var jsInitChecktimer = setTimeout (checkForJS_Finish, 20000);
  function checkForJS_Finish(){
     // Listen for messages from the popup
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, response) { .... `

Comment: I meant `load` event inside the content script, not the popup.

Comment: Um yes, I didn't know how to make it look like code inside a comment so it's a bit hard to see. So I did wrap up content.js code but only the second part. But maybe I should also wrap it around first part:  `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ from: 'content',from: 'content', subject: 'showPageAction' });`

Comment: Currently I have it like this: https://pastebin.com/1khmexXn.
I believe I must be wrapping it the wrong way? Thank you again for any direction! :)

Comment: Are you saying that this does not send the HTML as it exists *at the time the popup opens*? That appears to be what you intend, but we can't know for sure because you have not included `sendHorsesInformation`, whic is a part of the the data flow. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Hey Mayken, yes this does not always return the whole page as it is. I have included all the files I have, even the manifest. I've dumbed it down as much as I can. But I do have a question as @wOxxOm pointed out -> where did he think I should rather put the timeout? If you could shed some light on this this would be great :), thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK got it. Just had to move the checkForJS_Finish function with ajax function from popup.js inside content.js and it works.